# RoR/Postgres - Error with two column unique index. "duplicate key value violates unique constraint", even without any records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So Contract can have many Services. and the join table is ContractsService(contracts_services), pretty simple.

Index set with:

```
def change
  add_index :contracts_services, [:contract_id, :service_id], unique: true
end
```

If I try to add like this (or via the API, or in any way, so not specific to this piece of code):

```
ContractsService.where(contract_id: 16, service_id: 17).first_or_create!
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_contracts_services_on_contract_id_and_service_id"
DETAIL:  Key (contract_id, service_id)=(16, 17) already exists.
```

However:

```
irb(main):015:0> ContractsService.where(contract_id: 16, service_id: 17).count
D, [2017-10-26T07:25:01.782432 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contracts_services" WHERE "contracts_services"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "contracts_services"."contract_id" = $1 AND "contracts_services"."service_id" = $2  [["contract_id", 16], ["service_id", 17]]
=> 0
```

I'm stuck here, never seen this before. I'm I missing something simple? or is the index corrupt? Something else?

Comment: Hm, interesting.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio It's not a duplicate of that question, my issue is not with null indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have `default_scope` in `ContractsService` model.
Look at the SQL: `"contracts_services"."deleted_at" IS NULL`

And your unique index doesn't include `deleted_at` column.

If you will try `ContractsService.rewhere(contract_id: 16, service_id: 17).count` then you should find this record

Comment: "Note that unlike reorder, we’re only unscoping the named conditions – not the entire where statement." - `rewhere` wouldn't touch `deleted_at`.

Comment: Thanks! This is it. `acts_as_paranoid` deleted_at is a separate index. I guess I should combine them, what's the best way to say index those two column IF deleted_at is NULL otherwise ignore the unique constraint?

Comment: BTW I used: `ContractsService.only_deleted.where(contract_id: 16, service_id: 17).count # => 1`, `rewhere` didn't show it.

Comment: @PeterR: PG has partial unique indexes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-partial.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks!

Comment: This is what I went with `add_index :contracts_services, [:contract_id, :service_id], unique: true, where: "deleted_at = NULL"`